# How to build msi extension with setup.py using cx freeze

Tags: python

I wouldlike to create a .msi extension for my python script. With this file I wouldike to add possibility to the users to install python and install all depedencies of the project. I actually don't understand how can I do this. Here it's my setup.py

setup.py :

```
import os
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

    os.system('virtualenv sample/venv && sample\\venv\\Scripts\\activate && pip install -r requirements.txt')
    setup(name = "Myscript",
            version = "0.1",
            description = "My GUI application!",
            executables = [Executable("main.py", base=base)])
```

Answer (score 0):

Cxfreeze will automatically build all the dependencies inlcuding python and any other modules you have imported in your script. If you get any module not found error, you have to manually include it in the packages. Any files like images used needs to be explicitly included. Here is an example code for your reference -

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

build_exe_options = {'packages': ['os', 'tkinter', 'matplotlib.backends.backend_svg', 'subprocess'],
                     'namespace_packages': ['mpl_toolkits'],
                     'include_files':['input3.json', 'SF.xlsx', 'SF logo.ico', 'Operative Temperature.pkl',
                                      'Rect_icon.png', 'Soltissim logo.png', 'SF full logo.jpg', 'IES logo.jpg']}

base = None

if sys.platform == 'win32':
    base = 'Win32GUI'

setup ( name = 'Soltissim',
        version = '2',
        description = 'SF GUI',
        options = {'build_exe': build_exe_options},
        executables = [Executable('Soltissim.py', base=base, icon='SF logo.ico])
```